# Visual Studio File Conversion Fails

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to open this [project](http://www.cis.cornell.edu/courses/CIS3000/2010sp/labs/prog1/ShipDemo.zip) in VS 2010. However, it fails, and I am unable to open the project. Why could this be happening?

The project is XNA.

Here is an error message:

> The project file 'ShipDemo.csproj'
>   cannot be opened. The project type is
>   not supported by this installation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[XNA Game Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb200104.aspx) is built upon Visual Studio 2008.  They have not updated it to work with VS 2010 at this point.

In order to use XNA, you still need to work in VS 2008.

Comment: XNA projects are not supported by VS by default, so waiting for XNA Studio for VS2010 is all that we can do now.